# I'm looking for a text editor or viewer which when opening file will not read entire file and which supports quick movement between parts of file

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-10.04, text-editors

We've had similar question few days ago, but there the requirement was that it only reads a part of the file. There are also these windows questions: https://superuser.com/questions/4044/ and https://superuser.com/questions/3474 but I'm looking for program that works on Ubuntu.

My problem is that due to some bug my .xsession-errors started to increase at alarming rate and quickly took up all my remaining disk space (around 37.1GiB), as I explained in [Ubuntu: .xsession-errors ate 37.1 GiB of disk space: What is causing that?](https://superuser.com/questions/184830).

less proved to be useful there, but in files of that size, it was very difficult to get the idea what's going on using less. I'm looking for some program (GUI is a plus) which can read files of that size and allow quick scrolling through them or to at least be capable of going to certain position in a file, like for example 25%, 50% etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hex editors tend to be good at loading large files (I guess because they are used on memory dumps, and you can't open a 1GB memory dump on a machine with 1GB of RAM..)

E.g [lfhex](http://stoopidsimple.com/lfhex) - "lfhex is an application for viewing and editing files in hex, octal, binary, or ascii text. The main strength of lfhex is it's ability to work with files much larger than system memory (or address space for that matter!)."

Comment: I'll check it out.